# Setting the status name when setting the status on a GitHub commit

Tags: github-api, pygithub

I'm setting the status of commits to block Pull Request merges from an AWS CodeBuild job. I'm using PyGithub. Here's my code:

```
repo.get_commit(sha=sha).create_status(state=state,description=description)
```

I've set branch protection to block without `success`. My issue is that the only status name is `default` in the search.

Here's a current example of a Pull Request that has been recently approved: https://github.com/kjenney/pulumi-bootstrap/pull/12

How can I set the status name when I post it so that I can customize this name?

Answer (score 1):

Context sets the name of the status.

```
repo.get_commit(sha=sha).create_status(state=state,description=description,context='codebuild')
```